# Clementine Error: The stream is encrypted and decryption is not supported

Tags: clementine

So Clementine won't play some songs from my ipod and give the error in the title. Anyone knows if there is a way to fix this? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

There is a package called  `ubuntu-restricted-drivers` that support playback for mp3 and some other patented/restricted formats but this will probably be of no help. Those files you are talking about are mostlikely DRM protected and you will not be able to use those files on anything else than your Apple products (and even that usage seems limited). Their user agreement is far too restrictive for my taste. So no, nothing to be done here for those music files specifically.

Alternative: In my country I am allowed to download music files (even though this source itself might be illegal). So in my case I would download an OGG version of that music and use that for playback with Clementine.